# R Separate the post code with location name with space

Tags: r, regex, string

anyone can give some suggestion to separate the postcode with location name to 'Postcode' and 'Location', my data is something like:

```
my.data <- c("105 69 STOCKHOLM", "FI-40101 JYVÄSKYLÄ", "SE-831 88 ÖSTERSUND", 
    "85170 Le Poiré Sur Vie", "Chaoyang Distr.. CN-100027 BEIJING")
```

basically, do not have clear pattern how the how the first number or number like string separate with the city name.

Hope to have the result as

```
Postcode                     City
105 69                       STOCKHOLM
FI-40101                     JYVÄSKYLÄ
SE-831 88                    ÖSTERSUND
85170                        Le Poiré Sur Vie
Chaoyang Distr.. CN-100027   BEIJING
```

or if you think that is not possible, please also give me a comment

Comment: R doesn't understand what postal codes are. Unless you can come up with a rule that you could explain to a human on how exactly these strings need to be split, it's going to be hard to get a computer to do it. Do you just want all the letters after the last number in the string to be marked as "city"?

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, strsplit(my.data, "(?<=[0-9])\\s(?=[A-ZÖ]+)", perl = TRUE))` but note that a) I am not very experienced with regular expressions and b) the `"Ö"` in `ÖSTERSUND` is hard coded (because of a) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it

```
data.frame(postalCode = gsub('(.*\\d)\\D+$','\\1', my.data, perl = TRUE),
           city = gsub('.*\\d(\\D+)$','\\1', my.data, perl = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#                   postalCode              city
# 1                     105 69         STOCKHOLM
# 2                   FI-40101         JYVÄSKYLÄ
# 3                  SE-831 88         ÖSTERSUND
# 4                      85170  Le Poiré Sur Vie
# 5 Chaoyang Distr.. CN-100027           BEIJING
```

**Explanation**

The regex `.*\\d\\D+$` means:

- `.*` the string starts something/anything until
- `\\d\\D+$` there comes the last digit and everything afterwards is not a digit
- in `postalCode` we capture everything from start until the last digit (included)
- in `city` we capture everything from last digit (excluded) until the end

---

**Note**

You probably shouldn't rely too much on it for more general cases

```
# you can test and see what it yields with
my.data <- c(my.data,'postal 123 streetname 45 city', '831 88-SE Östersund')
```

Answer (score 0):

Every postal code ends with digit so this will be enough:

```
library(tidyverse)

my.data %>%
  str_match('(.*\\d) (.*)') %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(2:3) %>%
  set_names(c('Postcode', 'City'))
```